# jquery .validate() variable error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using multiple languages on this website and want to display the errors in the different languages.  I was wondering if it is possible to use variables in the custom error messages.

Here is the snippet of the JavaScript code:

```
$('form').validate({
$.ajax({
    url: 'notification.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        return notification = data;
    }
});
rules: {
    qty: {
        required:   true,
        digits:     true
    }
},
messages: {
    qty: {
        required:   notification['qty_error'],
        digits:     notification['qty_error2']
    }
},
invalidHandler: function () {
    alert(notification['error2']);
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url:    $('form').attr('action'),
        type:   'post',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'notification.php',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#notification .container').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">'+ data.confirm1 + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                    $('#notification .success').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
});
```

If not what is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place `.ajax()` inside of `.validate()` like you've done here...

```
$('form').validate({
    $.ajax({ ... });  // <-- remove this
    ...
});
```

Only the designated rules, options, and callback functions as per [the jQuery Validate plugin documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) can ever go inside of `.validate()`.

I see you've already included the same `.ajax()` code inside the `submitHandler` callback function.  This is perfectly correct, so just remove the `.ajax()` as indicated above.

```
$('form').validate({
    // rules, options & callback functions
    ...
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({ ... });  // <-- ajax always belongs here
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

As far as your original question, **yes**, you can use variables in place of the messages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var message_1 = "my custom message 1";

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                required: message_1
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/PWdke/

To change the messages dynamically (after the plugin is initialized) would require [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var message_1 = "my custom message 1",
        message_3 = "my custom message 3";

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                required: message_1
            }
        }
    });

    // programatically over-ride initialized rules/messages below

    $('input[name="field1"]').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: message_3
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/PWdke/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your current script is syntactically incorrect, you can do something like

```
var validator = $('form').validate({
    rules: {
        qty: {
            required:   true,
            digits:     true
        }
    },
    messages: {
    },
    invalidHandler: function () {
        alert(notification['error2']);
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url:    $('form').attr('action'),
            type:   'post',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'notification.php',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#notification .container').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">'+ data.confirm1 + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                        $('#notification .success').fadeIn('slow');
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'notification.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var notification = {
            qty: {
                required: data['qty_error'],
                    digits: notification['qty_error2']
            }
        };

        validator.settings.messages = notification
    }
});
```

Comment: @koala_dev, please don't edit the code in somebody else's answer.

Comment: Arun, putting the `.ajax()` by itself... won't this just cause an ajax submission immediately upon page load?  He already has similar `.ajax()` inside his `submitHandler` callback function.

Comment: thanks all for the help but I still have one issue.  Since the variables are stored originally in php and changed based on the language chosen how do i convert the php variables into javascript variables?  This is why i used the Ajax at the start because I couldn't think of another way.

Comment: @Sparky Sorry, I just thought it was a little overlook that I could easily fix, won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error at:

```
$('form').validate({
$.ajax({
    url: 'notification.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        return notification = data;
    }
});
```

Separate your ajax from validate...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'notification.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        return notification = data;
    }
});

$('form').validate({
    /*rules: ... */
})
```

Comment: He doesn't need to "separate".  `.ajax()` belongs inside the plugin's `submitHandler` callback function.  Putting it alone will cause an ajax submission on page load.